# Node - static file with get param not found

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a build script for the front end of my app - I use Gulp for minifying / concatenating / etc. I also use Gulp to cache bust the newly created files - this just appends a get param with a timestamp, e.g.

```
<script src='script.js?t=1450118355044'></script>
```

Everything works fine until I attempt the cache busting (appending the 't' param). As soon as the get param is appended node gives a file not found error.

Any ideas?!

Comment: Are you running a server with node? Or where does the error message come from?

Comment: That's a limitation of whatever server side code you are using to serve the static files. We can't see that code.

Comment: I'm just using app.use(express.static('[path to my app]')); As I say it all works fine until I add the get param.

Comment: Wondering if actually your whole code is not working and that when you put this query parameter, the browser cache gets passed by and then you see the error.